# Ionic 2 searchbar filter by 2 properties

Tags: json, angular, ionic2

I have a database read that returns me a JSON i'm using in my `*ngFor=""`, in the same page i have a search bar that searchs by the user name, but i also need it o search by the user's description (if it contais the word i'm typing).

Here's my code:

My searchbar:

```
<ion-searchbar placeholder="Search..." (ionInput)="searchUser($event)"></ion-searchbar>
```

My searchUser method (the same one ionic 2 docs gives you):

```
searchUser(ev: any) {
  // Reset items back to all of the items
  this.initializeItems();

  // set val to the value of the searchbar
  let val = ev.target.value;

  // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
  if (val && val.trim() != '') {
    this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
      return (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    })
  }
}
```

And an example of my JSON

```
{
  "key": {
    "name": name,
    "description": desc,
    "city": city,
    "state": state,
  }, ...
}
```

The only thing i tried so far is add an `&& item.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1` to my return, but i get nothing.

How is the best way to achieve this? With a provider? A correct line of code in my return?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use OR `||` operator instead of AND `&&`.
With `&&` you will see only results which matches both *name* and *description*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var searchedText = item['name'] + item['surname'];
return (searchedText.toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase()));
```

Define extra field that you want to search.